# Inclusion of CSS3 in .net3.5

Tags: .net, css

I have used some of the features of css3 in my project but it is showing me error. I am using .net 3.5.
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
these are the styles for which i am getting error. What i need to do for using css3 features.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [CSS3 Intellisense schema plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/)... or just ignore it when Visual Studio complains about CSS properties.

Comment: The Visual Studio team isn't really involved with the IE team, and IE *has* `border-radius` and not just since last week.

Comment: @Joey - the original question does not seem to be talking about IE, but rather intellisense errors in visual studio for CSS3 features.

Comment: @dbaseman The Plugin you have suggested is for visual studio 2010 but i am using 2008.

Comment: Mystere Man, that was just a reply to an off-hand comment they made in the answer which was really off-topic and far from reality.

Comment: @dbaseman yes you were right i ignored those errors and my code is working fine now i am getting the desired result. Thanks